# Looping stdClass object and getting contents in a variable

Tags: php, stdclass

Following is the output of my stdClass object:

```
stdClass Object ( 
      [all] => 0 
      [book] => 0 
      [title] => 1 
      [author] => 1 
      [content] => 0 
      [source] => 0 
     )
```

I want to store the elements that have a value `1` in a variable.

Suppose, in the above example, I want to store `$a='author' . 'title'`. Is this possible by using `foreach` or any other tidy approach, instead of manually checking for each whether they have a value of `1` or not and then storing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I see to do that is to use a foreach:

```
$myStdClass = /* ... */;
$a = '';

foreach ($myStdClass as $key => $value) {
    if ($value) {
        $a .= $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: well value would also cast to boolean true if there is another string in there... however if only 0/1 occur its fine

Answer (score 1):

One-liner solution:

```
$c = new stdClass();
$c->all = 0;
$c->book = 0;
$c->title = 1;
$c->author = 1;
$c->content = 0;
$c->source = 0;

$a = implode(',',  array_keys( array_filter( (array)$c) ) );

var_dump($a);
```

Would yield

```
string(12) "title,author"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$result = '';
foreach($your_stdclass as $key => $value) {
 if($value == '1') {
  $result .= $key;
 }
}
echo $result;
?>
```

that appears to be what you ask altough i dont know how that makes sense